# Problem with Identity token reset Password ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I'm adding the "Forgot password" option in my project. The problem is that when I click on the link which was sent in email, the token changes some characters. I inspected the link element received in the email and it's correct. The problem is that when I click on the link to open it, then the bug occurs.

Example: In the correct token, a letter that was "a" will go to "A", "b" to "B" was changed to uppercase as you can see in the print in attach below

[image]

```
var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

when the controller ResetPassword is called:

```
user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(resetPasswordModel.Email);
var resetPassResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, resetPasswordModel.Token, resetPasswordModel.Password);
if (!resetPassResult.Succeeded) //get invalid token here =/
{
    return false;
}
```

**Update**
i got fix by using follow code:

```
 var token = resetPasswordModel.Token.Replace("%20","+").Replace(" ", "+");
```

Comment: You should encode your token using `UrlEncoding` algorithm, before using it in URL.

Comment: Please add your solution as an _answer_ instead of editing it into your original _question_. We try to strictly adhere to the question and answer format around here. (There's absolutely no problem answering your own question if you're concerned about that.)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
yes, i already try use UrlEncoding but was useless.

fix using follow code

```
 var token = resetPasswordModel.Token.Replace("%20","+").Replace(" ", "+");
```